# axios interceptor code is not covered in jest

Tags: axios, mocking, ts-jest, jest-mock-axios

When running jest test having Axios interceptor mocks the code is not covered for interceptor

The Axios code:

[image: The Axios code]

jest tests
[image]

The code coverage
[image]

I want 100% code coverage but interceptor code is not covered here

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post code as plain text with correct format.